# I tried to parse a JSON file on my app but even if there is no error, my app doesn't run on the emulator

Tags: json, kotlin, parsing

The problem might be that the app can't reach the json file I tried to parse it to.No error pops up in the run or build but it stops at"11/23 23:14:38: Launching 'app' on Device 4.Install successfully finished in 325 ms."Below is my code:

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation", "NotifyDataSetChanged")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val usersList: ArrayList<UserModelClass> = ArrayList()

        try {
            val obj = JSONObject(getJSONFromAssets()!!)
            val usersArray = obj.getJSONArray("owner")

            for (i in 0 until usersArray.length()) {

                val user = usersArray.getJSONObject(i)

                val login = user.getInt("id")
                val name = user.getString("name")
                val url = user.getString("url")
                val followers_url = user.getString("followers")
                val starred_url = user.getString("stars")

              val userDetails =
                    UserModelClass(login, name, url, followers_url , starred_url)

                // add the details in the list
                usersList.add(userDetails)
            }
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            //exception
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvUsersList)

        val adapter = UserAdapter(this, usersList)

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun getJSONFromAssets(): String? {

        var json: String? = null
        val charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8
        try {
            val myUsersJSONFile = assets.open("JSON.json")
            val size = myUsersJSONFile.available()
            val buffer = ByteArray(size)
            myUsersJSONFile.read(buffer)
            myUsersJSONFile.close()
            json = String(buffer, charset)
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
            return null
        }
        return json
    }

}
```

UserAdapter

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup


    class UserAdapter( val context: Context,  val items: ArrayList<UserModelClass>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<UserViewHolder>() {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
            return UserViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.item_user,
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.bind(items[position])
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return items.size
        }
    }
```

UserViewHolder

```
class UserViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    // Holds the TextView that will add each item to
    var  tvId : TextView
    var tvName : TextView
    var tvURL : TextView
    var tvFollowers : TextView
    var tvStars : TextView

    init {
        tvId = view.findViewById(R.id.tvId)
        tvName = view.findViewById(R.id.tvName)
        tvURL = view.findViewById(R.id.tvURL)
        tvFollowers = view.findViewById(R.id.tvFollowers)
        tvStars = view.findViewById(R.id.tvStars)
    }

    fun bind(item: UserModelClass) {
        tvId.text = item.login.toString()
        tvName.text = item.node_id
        tvURL.text = item.avatar_url
        tvFollowers.text = item.followers_url.toString()
        tvStars.text = item.starred_url.toString()

    }
}
```

UserModelClass

```
class UserModelClass(
    val login: Int,
    val node_id: String,
    val avatar_url: String,
    val followers_url: String,
    val starred_url: String
        )
```

Json.json

I don't need all the information from the json, I selected some of them

```
{
  "total_count": 357602,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 23096959,
      "node_id": "...",
      "name": "...",
      "full_name": "...",
      "private": false,
      "owner": {
        "login": "...",
        "id": 4314092,
        "node_id": "...",
        "avatar_url": "https://...",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/golang",
        "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/golang/followers",
        "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/golang/following{/other_user}",
        "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/golang/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems you are parsing it wrong. In your json, `items` is the array and `owner` is an object inside `items` array item.

You cannot access owner directly. Also you should give exact keys.
Like `"followers_url"` not just `"followers"`

Try the below code.

```
try {
            val obj = JSONObject(getJSONFromAssets()!!)
            val itemsArray = obj.getJSONArray("items")

            for (i in 0 until itemsArray.length()) {

                val user = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i)
                val name = user.getString("name") // Getting name from item object
                val owner = user.getJSONObject("owner") //Getting owner object from item object
    //And below you need to  get items from owner object not the user object.
                val login = owner.getInt("id")
                val url = owner.getString("url")
                val followers_url = owner.getString("followers_url")
                val starred_url = owner.getString("starred_url")

              val userDetails =
                    UserModelClass(login, name, url, followers_url , starred_url)

                // add the details in the list
                usersList.add(userDetails)
            }
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            //exception
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I made the changes but it still does not work

Comment: What error it shows in logcat?

Comment: E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~aQsgdnVpSDyH0yXIcST-ZQ==/com.example.githubtrending-jiu-eZzU9fKrBp1xiqrMEg==/base.apk
Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.githubtrending/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory